# ember-drag-sort custom placeholder dropzone element?

Tags: ember.js, ember-drag-sort

Is it possible to replace the default square placeholder element? Ideally I'd like to have a placeholder under an empty list that reads something like "No Items in List" & then when an item from a different list is dragged over such element it adds it to the list like the normal functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this can be done with simple CSS:

```
.dragSortList.-isEmpty:not(.-isDragging):after {
  content: "No Items in List";
}
```

You can tweak it with classes `-isDragging`, `-isDraggingOver` and `-isDragged`.

See [demo on Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/582e1b802fddc938c12e894b01a883c4?numColumns=2&openFiles=styles.app.css%2Ctemplates.application.hbs).